# How do I accomplish array part in Perl

Tags: python, perl

```
a = [-1, 1, 66.25, 333, 333, 1234.5]
print a[4][1]; #it prints 3
```

Is there a way to do that in Perl.

Comment: I want to try to break a big number, num = 23345566699696960505930292020, into each digit. I know that in Python, I can do something like num[4] will return the fifth element of that big number. Is there a way to do that in Perl?

Comment: [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) or [substr](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html). A string isn't an array and can't be indexed like an array.

Comment: `print substr($a->[4],1,1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with hobbs...  but to be clear, in your example above, I think this is what you want from Perl:

```
my @a = (-1, 1, 66.25, 333, 333, 1234.5);
print substr ($a[4], 1, 1); #it prints 3
```

Unfortunately, this example is a bit ambiguous because the `4` and the `1` are both zero-based, and I really wasn't sure which 333 you wanted or which digit amongst the 333 you wanted...  Is Python zero-based?  I'm sure it was unintentional, but that was about the worst example of the lot.

Maybe this one is better:

```
print substr ($a[5], 3, 1);  # prints '4' from '1234.5'
```